# How to click on a button with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to use the Python Selenium API in order to click on a button. The HTML code is as follows:

```
<button class="btn wizard-next btn-primary" type="button">Weiter</button>
```

How to best identify this element? I was trying the following code

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn wizard-next btn-primary").click()
```

but got an error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted
```

What else can I do to select this element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `find_element_by_class_name()` if class name value contains spaces.
Try:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn wizard-next btn-primary']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css selector also

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("btn").click()
```

Comment: Can I use that even there is another button on that same page?

Comment: In that case you have to be more specific about the element css selector. for example if it is a form then you can change it to `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div#formID > btn").click()` by this way you won't click on different element on the page