# How to click on a button which has no fixed class value? But it have a fixed 'data-testid'

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, automation

How to click on a button which has no fixed class value? But it have a fixed 'data-testid'.

Using JS or Python How to achieve that?

```
document.getElementById("myCheck").click();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to click on a button with Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38220902/how-to-click-on-a-button-with-selenium)

Comment: yes that also helps :) thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) which allows any valid CSS selector (i.e: attribute selector).

**Demo:**

```js
function muFunction(){
  alert('Hi');
}

document.querySelector("[data-testid='123']").click();
```

```html
<button data-testid="123" onclick="muFunction()">My Button</button>
```